# How can I run a Microsoft Virtual PC image of XP with IE6 on XP?

Tags: internet-explorer-6, virtual-pc, vmc

The last time I wanted to test IE6 with the developer toolbar enabled, I simply installed Microsoft Virtual PC, downloaded the XP with IE6 VMC and away I went.

However, I'm trying to do this today and having a nightmare of a time.  It seems that Microsoft, although providing Microsoft Virtual PC, are no longer providing VMCs on their "Internet Explorer Application Compatibility VPC Image" page, only VHDs.  VHDs require *Windows* Virtual PC, not *Microsoft* Virtual PC (silly me!), which they don't want you to have if you're on XP.

So going by the lesson in non-usability that is the maze of links on microsoft.com, it seems that I'm kind of screwed.  I am getting a laptop next month with one of their shiny new operating systems on it, but right now I'm still a developer who has XP and needs to fix an IE6 issue.  It seems a little antagonistic to suddenly prevent XP users from being able to perform their duties using the same tools as everyone else; not exactly a sure-fire way to get me rushing out to buy VS2010.

Is there any way to get Windows Virtual PC onto XP, a way to run a VHD under Microsoft Virtual PC or even just a super-top-secret page where they are providing VMCs?

Comment: @All: pesonally, I'd consider this to be just _barely_ programming-related, and belonging on SO, since he's setting up the VPC specifically to test his code with IE6. Consider not closing this.

Comment: @tags2k: -1 for jumping to conclusions about nasty, evil Microsoft, when it's really a nasty, evil, user rtfm error.

Comment: Okay, point taken but it's not *quite* as you say it is.  The download page points to Windows Virtual PC, which isn't available for XP, and there's no mention of Microsoft Virtual PC anywhere on the site.  It's not hard to get confused when the M in RTFM is one non-specific line on a page which directs me to the wrong software.

Comment: -3 for misunderstanding some terminology which isn't clearly explained and becoming irritated enough to ask the question publicly? How very dare I!  :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misunderstand how Virtual PC works. You can create a VMC file by creating a new Virtual PC then choosing to use an existing VHD rather than create a new one. There is nothing specific about VHDs that limit them to the new Win7 virtualization package.

Whilst I agree the VirtualPC for XP/Vista download is now relegated to the MS download site there's nothing stopping you using the IE6 virtual hard drives at all and indeed the instructions on how to use it are on the [download page](http://www.microsoft.com/Downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=21eabb90-958f-4b64-b5f1-73d0a413c8ef&displaylang=en#Instructions) itself.

Answer (score 0):

.... would VirtualBox work for you? I do my ie6 testing on Linux/Mac under that.